# Generate exception from a C library function that forces quit

Tags: c++, exception, exit

I am trying to wrap a C library function using C++. The function attempts to initialize a device. On error, it forces the execution of the program to terminate (probably with an `exit(1)`). I would like to throw an exception on error instead. Is there any way to do this without editing the C source?

Can I somehow disallow the called function to terminate the program?

Answer (score 1):

Install `atexit` handler, throw exception from handler. Ugh.

PS. So, C++ exception, as people pointed out, does not work, then we use C "exception":

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <csetjmp>

jmp_buf buf;
void foo ()
{
        longjmp (buf, 1);
}

void bar () { exit(-1); }

int
main ()
{
        atexit (foo);


        if (setjmp (buf))
        {
                bar ();
        }
        else
        {
                std::cout << "graceful" << std::endl;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will call your function, but the process will be terminated after that anyway, so it won't help

Comment: Bad library. I feel dirty :)

Comment: will that work? I'm reading http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atexit/ "[...] If a function registered with atexit throws an exception for which it does not provide a handler, terminate is automatically called (C++)."

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix/Linux, you can check with `strace` what exactly your library calls, then you can override called function using `LD_PRELOAD`.

Answer (score 0):

Not a super nice solution, but one which should work: fork a new process and call that C function in the child process. In the parent process, wait for the child to finish, check the error code, if it is 1, which means `exit(1)` was called, throw an exception.